# Issue with Haml files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Hi i converting rails views from erb to Haml .The issue i faced is when use the form_for the haml throws the  UNEXPECTED $end error. I am sure i did the space indentation well with in form_for .......Even if i use "each do" loop is says the same error. if i revert the haml to erb it works fine.

Rails version i used : 2.3.2 & i installed haml gem 2.2.19 as well as haml plugin also.

my controller code :

```
def new
    @user = User.new
end
```

My View code :

```
.contentContainer.signup
 - form_for(@user) do |f|
```

Comment: is the "- form_for" really indented one space? HAML needs two, and they must be spaces, not tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your haml indentation is perfect.

```
.contentContainer.signup
  - form_for(@user) do |f|
    = f.text_field :name
```

Comment: yes i did the indentation perfectly but even if use each do loop it says me the same error .

Comment: If that's not an indictment on HAML, I don't know what is.

Comment: You need to edit and paste your entire Haml template in the question.

Comment: Fewer, cleaner lines with indentation ... vs. more, noisier lines with symbols?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including `- end` in your templates? Haml takes care of `end`s for you, so if you add your own, it won't work.

Can you paste your entire template (in a code block, so it's formatted properly)?

Answer (score 0):

There's also a good command-line tool to make transition easier: html2haml. It doesn't always produce the prettiest haml, but it certainly works.

Hey, there's even a web-based form for this: http://html2haml.heroku.com/

Generally, be sure your indentation is perfect. haml is very particular about indentation. If you use a decent editor (such as textmate or vim) this is an easy task.

Answer (score -1):

If the last line in file is indented there has to be an addidtional, empty line.